# How to select specific instance of Vue component when multiple instances exist in DOM

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component as defined by the following template, assume it's called `CompositeComponent`:

```
<template>
    <div class="item-and-qualifiers-selector">
        <special-list
            :props="someProps"
        ></special-list>
        <another-special-list
            :id="'anotherSpecialList1'"
            :list-items="someListItems"
        ></another-special-list>
        <another-special-list
            :id="'anotherSpecialList2'"
            :list-items="someMoreListItems"
        ></another-special-list>
    </div>
</template>
```

The `CompositeComponent` in constructed of two different components, `SpecialList` and `AnotherSpecialList`, where `AnotherSpecialList` appears twice within the structure of the `CompositeComponent`. Assume the following basic component design for `AnotherSpecialList`:

```
export default {
    name: 'AnotherSpecialList',
    props: {
        listItems: { type: Array, required: true },
        id: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            activeListItem: null
        };
    },
    created() {
        document.addEventListener('focusin', this.focusChanged);
    },
    methods: {
        focusChanged() {
            if (document.activeElement.id === 'anotherSpecialList1') {
                console.log('Focussed on the first special list');
                this.activeListItem = this.listItems[0];
            } else if (document.activeElement.id === 'anotherSpecialList2') {
                console.log('Focussed on the second special list');
                this.activeListItem = this.listItems[0];
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

When the DOM's current focus is the `SpecialList`, I want to tab from the `SpecialList` into the first instance of `AnotherSpecialList` and assign the `activeListItem` of `AnotherSpecialList` where `id === anotherSpecialList1` to `listItems[0]`, i.e., `this.activeListItem = listItems[0]`. Then, similarly, when the DOM's current focus is the `AnotherSpecialList` where `id === anotherSpecialList1`, I want to tab from that instance into the second instance of `AnotherSpecialList` where `id === anotherSpecialList2` and assign the `activeListItem` of `AnotherSpecialList` where `id === anotherSpecialList2` to `listItems[0]`.

Currently, I've got a listener attached to `focusin` which is created in `mounted`, which is bound to `focusChanged`. I'm fetching the document's `activeElement` and checking the `id` against the two values that have been specified, `anotherSpecialList1` and `anotherSpecialList2`. The problem I'm facing with the logic of `this.activeListItem = this.listItems[0];` is that it is happening for both instances of `AnotherSpecialList`. Is there a way where I can select a specific instance of `AnotherSpecialList` and only execute the logic on the instance that matches the one that is the current focus of the DOM?

Comment: You should move the logic to the parent component.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim why?

Comment: Because then you can decide which instance should assign its `activeListItem`. The way things are set up now both of them will assign that value if either one receives focus.

Comment: I think a much simpler method would be to just use a `focus` event listener on the root element of the `AnotherSpecialList` component. Then you won't need all that complex logic to determine which instance received focus.

Comment: No worries. So would you go about using events? Could you provide me with an example of your suggestion, please?

Comment: Can you provide the template for `AnotherSpecialList`?

Comment: You should give each component a unique key and work with that.